# How to Output the Reverse of a Map [Java]

Tags: java, dictionary

The problem goes as follows: Jane has friends who she associates a number with. I must output the friends from the least amount of likes to the most likes.

My main curiosity is how can I reverse the order of the map values when outputting.
In my code I had to extract the values through an `Iterator` (I was unable to use a Collection directly) and then store each String into an `ArrayList` by inserting each consecutive element at index 0. This, as a result, reversed the order which worked I suppose.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import static java.lang.System.*;

public class Friends {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {
        Scanner line = new Scanner(new File("friends.dat"));
        int trials = line.nextInt();
        for(int k = 0 ; k < trials ; k++)
        {
            TreeMap<Integer, String> m = new TreeMap<Integer,String>();
            int subtrials = line.nextInt();

            for(int a = 0; a < subtrials ; a++)
            {
                String name = line.next();
                int likes = line.nextInt();
                m.put(likes,name);
            }

            Iterator iter = m.values().iterator();       //**Code of interest starts here**
            ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

            while(iter.hasNext()) {

                list.add(0, (String)iter.next());
            }

            for(int a = 0 ; a < list.size() ; a++)
            {
                if(a == list.size() - 1)
                    out.print(list.get(a));
                else
                    out.print(list.get(a) + ", ");
            }
            out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a custom [comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#TreeMap(java.util.Comparator)) to reverse the order of entries in the map (note that this only applies to TreeMap - other map implementations don't care about ordering).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    TreeMap<Integer, String> map = new TreeMap<>((key1, key2) -> Integer.compare(key2, key1)); //Custom comparator.
    map.put(1, "Bob");
    map.put(3, "Baz");
    map.put(2, "Foo");

    System.out.println(map);
}
```

Comment: `key2 - key1` is a bad Comparator; it can suffer from overflow errors.  Use `Integer.compare(key2, key1)`

Comment: I'm assuming that 'Over' refers to overflow?  If we're dealing with incredibly large numbers (as in the upper and lower bounds of int), then yes, I agree.  The purpose of this exercise was just to illustrate that a Comparator can be used to solve the OP

Answer (score 1):

Using the number of likes as a key seems strange, as multiple friends might have the same number of likes.

In Java 8, I'd do the following:

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("Jack", 7);
map.put("Jill", 3);
map.put("John", 12);

map.entrySet()
   .stream()
   .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue((a, b) -> b.compareTo(a)))
   .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Essentially, this turns the map entries into a stream, compares them by value using a comparator that reverses the natural order, and then prints out every entry.

Which results in:

```
John=12
Jack=7
Jill=3
```

Comment: I forgot the mention that no two people will have the same amount of likes. Either way, your code is very...very concise. I am not familiar with Java 8. Could you please explain the last 4 lines?

Comment: @IanLimarta added some basic explanation to my answer. For anything beyond that, I suggest you start reading into Java streams and lambdas. If you can actually use the number of likes as keys, the [solution provided by @RiaanNel](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40988439/3558960) is better, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
m.forEach((a,b)->System.out.print(b+", "));
```

This will give you a sorted map, from the least amount of likes to the most likes.
If you want a sorted map from the most likes to the least amount of likes, you can do this:

```
TreeMap<Integer, String> m = new TreeMap<Integer,String>(Collections.reverseOrder());
```

Answer (score -1):

You could simply [reverse](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverse(java.util.List)) your list.

```
 list.reverse();
```

Alternately, you could use the [TreeMap constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#TreeMap(java.util.Comparator)) with a reverse comparator, to store the map in descending order.

```
... = new TreeMap<>(Collections.reverseOrder(Integer::compare));
```

Comment: Yes, but it is just as equivalent as adding each element at index zero. I was hoping for something that when directly from the Map object to output.

Comment: .reverse() is much more efficient than inserting each element at position 0, successively.